Evaluate the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}x(\ln\vert x \vert)^2$.
The problem:
Evaluate the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}x(\ln\vert x \vert)^2$.
The solution:
$0$
What I have tried:
L'Hôpital's rule has not been introduced in my class yet, so I assume I am not use it to solve this problem. What has been introduced on the other hand are these following growth properties for exp and ln:
If $a\gt0$, then (a) $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^a}{e^x}=0$, (b) $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\ln{x}}{x^a}=0$, (c) $\lim_{x\to -\infty} |x|^ae^x=0$, (d) $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^a\ln{x}=0$.
Now, I am either to utilize these properties somehow or perhaps it could just be solved as simply as "oh, plugging in $x=0$ will obviously have the limit as a whole approach $0$".
My question:
The latter is the only way I can think of solving this problem, but it isn't the right way, is it? It feels like a weak explanation and maybe even incorrect.

It is enough to show that $\lim_{x\to0} \sqrt{|x|}\ln|x|=0.$

If you use $(d)$ with $a=1/2$ you're done

@SineoftheTime Like this: $\lim_{x\to 0}x(\ln\vert x \vert)^2 = 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{x}\ln{|x|} = 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{x\to 0}x^{\frac{1}{2}}\ln{|x|}=0$?

We ignore that the limit in the property is approaching $0^+$ and not $0$?

you can change the sign and see the limit as $x\to 0^-$

Do you mean that the property is also applicable for when $x\to 0^-$?

let for example $x=-u$, then you consider $\lim_{u\to 0^-}$. Anyways, you can use the continuity of $|\cdot|$ and follow Bob Dobbs's hint

For all $0\neq x\in\Bbb R,$
$$-|x|\ln^2|x|\leq x\ln^2|x|\leq |x|\ln^2|x|.$$
Due to Sandwich theorem, to show that $\lim_{x\to0}x\ln^2|x|=0$ it is enough to show that
$$\lim_{x\to0}|x|\ln^2|x|
=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\sqrt{|x|}\ln|x|\right)^2=0.$$
Because of product rule for limits, it is enought to show that
$$\lim_{x\to0}\sqrt{|x|}\ln|x|=
\lim_{x\to0^\color{red}{+}}x^{\frac12}\ln x=0.$$
The last equality is true by (d).

You can use any of the given properties which are equivalent, for example using (a), by $x=\pm e^{-y}\to 0$ with $y\to \infty$
$$\left|x(\ln\vert x \vert)^2\right| =\frac{y^2}{e^y}\to 0$$
